# How do you filter your friends to find someone in your friend list?

Tags: facebook

I have listed all of my friends according to how I know them.  I used to be able to find friends by clicking on that list - (High School Friends) (work) etc.  Now I can not sort my friends when I want to find one.  Is there a way to go back to filtering the friends I want to talk to according to my own lists I have created?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to go http://www.facebook.com/bookmarks/lists and then select which list you want. Alternatively you can search for the list in the search bar at the top of every page.